# Reference from literal

Tags: c++

I am calling a function with the signature

```
void setValue(int& data)
```

I would like to pass a literal number to it:

```
setValue(1);
```

But I get:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

Is there a way I can make this work without changing the function (it's in a library) and without assigning each literal value to a variable?

Comment: `setValue(1);` is passing rvalue-> to bind you need either `const&` or `&&`.

Comment: @JeJo Can I change something *at the call site* to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `setValue` does not actually modify its argument and just has a wrong signature which you cannot change, here is an approach which is not thread-safe among other things:

```
#include <iostream>

void setValue(int &i)
{
  std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
}

int& evil(int i)
{
  static int j;
  j = i;
  return j;
}

int main()
{
  setValue(evil(1));
  setValue(evil(2));
}
```

Comment: `evil()` would be thread-safe if you used a `thread_local` (or equivalent) variable instead of a `static` variable

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the argument as being an int&, you are saying that the function called can change the value ***and the caller will see the change***.

So it is no longer valid to pass a literal value then because how could the function possibly change the given value of a literal?

If you don't want the `setValue` to be able to change the given value, make the argument either be an `int` or `const int&`.  And if you ***do*** want the `setValue` function to be able to change the value, then the caller must declare a non-const ***variable*** to hold the int and pass in that.

Comment: I don't know why the library author made it a reference. The function immediately copies the value and then the reference is never used/changed anymore.

Comment: That shows that the library author did not understand the purpose of const correctness.

When I encounter such issues, I either a) deal with the fact that I have to declare a variable before calling the function or b) write a simple inline wrapper function that does it for me and then calls the function.  Annoying, yes, but if it's a function you call many times, it might be worth it

Comment: Either that or the author originally intended the function to change the given value, then changed his/her mind and never fixed the signature

Answer (score 0):

> Can I change something at the call site to make it work

The problem with your code is that you declared your function to expect a reference, which means the compiler has to prepare the code to allow the function to change whatever you pass into it at the call site. So yes, sure, you can declare a variable, set it to 1 and call your function with it.

Contrast this with a **constant** reference in the declaration, where the compiler knows you won't change it inside the function, and then you can pass a literal in without issues. In fact, any logical, thought out design will make setters accept constant parameters because it won't change them, it will just store a possibly processed value in its state.

Comment: As an aside, `int const&` is nonsense that shows even more problems with your design, because there's no reason you need the indirect reference there. Just pass the integer since it's register-sized (or smaller).

Comment: I don't know why the library author made it a reference. The function immediately copies the value and then the reference is never used/changed anymore.

Comment: Precisely, setters don't change their arguments, it's why they should be constant, and, if register-sized values, not references.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to „what do I do if a library has a bad interface and I can't change it“ is usually „write a wrapper“. Assuming this is a method of some class `BadLibraryClass`, you could do something like:

```cpp
class Wrapper {
public:
    BadLibraryClass inner;

    setValue(int i) {
        inner.setValue(i); // i is an lvalue
    }
};
```

This is just a crude example. Perhaps `inner` is better off being a pointer, a reference or even a smart pointer. Perhaps you want a conversion operator to `BadLibraryClass`. Perhaps you can use inheritance to expose other methods of `BadLibraryClass`.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, though it may get a bit confusing. It also technically violates the OP's rule _"without assigning each literal value to a variable"_, though that's true of any solution that doesn't modify the interface ;)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, references keeps the addresses of the variable. 1 is not variable. It is temporary.

Take a look this article(this is a quote from [this](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Emyers/cop4530/notes/references2.html) site)

> c++11 introduced a new kind of reference variable -- an r-value reference

> To declare one, use && after a type

```
int & // type designation for an L-value reference

int && // type designation for an R-value reference
```

> - L-value references can only refer to L-values
> - R-value references can reference to R-values (temporaries)

```
int x, y, z;        // regular variables

int & r = x;        // L-value reference to the variable x

int & r2 = x + y;   // This would be ILLEGAL, since x + y is an R-value

int && r3 = x + y;  // LEGAL. R-value reference, referring to R-value
```

So you can use (But this is not useful. It may be more useful if you write this in plain without rvalue or lvalue.):

```
void setValue(int&& data)
setValue(1);
```

Or you can use that:

```
void setValue(int& data)
int a = 11;
setValue(a);
```

**Don't forget for second example. If you change the value of `data` parameter. You will have change the `a` variable value.**

Comment: "*1 is not variable. It is temporary*" - not exactly. It is more accurate to say that `1` itself is not a temporary, both rather is a **compile-time constant** that causes the compiler to *create* a temporary `int` at the site where `1` is passed to `setValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

Use the result of assignment:

```
static int _data;
void myCall() {
  setValue((_data = 3));
}
```

Write a wrapper:

```
struct setValueW {
  int _data;
  
  // constructor
  setValueW(int _data) : _data(_data) {
    setValue(_data);
  }
  
  // if you want to call it again
  void operator()() {
    setValue(_data);
  }
};

void myCall2() {
  setValueW(3);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**No, you can't.**

An lvalue reference like that binds to a variable (roughly speaking).

Your literal is not such a thing. It never had a name, and may not even have a home in memory.

Your two options are the two things you ruled out, I'm afraid.

---

For what it's worth, this is not your fault: that is a rather poor setter. It should take `const int&` (which will automatically *create* a nice temporary variable for you out of the literal!), or even just `const int`.